# When considering $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{g(n)}f_n(x)$, $g(n)\to \infty$ does $g$ matter when $f_n(x)$ is dominated?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

When considering $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{g(n)}f_n(x)$, $g(n)\to \infty$ does $g$ matter when $f_n(x)$ is dominated?

I was solving the following problem $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{e^n}\frac{x}{1+nx^2}$$ to my suprise it was not DCT or MCT, but simply integrating and calculating the limit. But then it hit me that the bound $e^n$ influences the result. If it was $n$ then the result would be 0, if it is $e^n$ it would be $1$. However, when the function inside is dominated it does not really matter how fast the bounds grow as pointwise $\chi_{[0,g(n)]}\to \chi_{[0,\infty)}$ What is the intuition behind this phenomena?

Comment: How would you use DCT or MCT in computing $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_0^{e^n}\frac{x}{1+nx^2}dx \ ?$$ It's not applicable here.

Comment: @surb Correct, that is exactly my point! The bound matters here. But if DCT did apply the bound does not matter. Whats up with that?

Comment: There is also an $n$ inside the integrand, $e^n$ grows way faster than $n$, the increasing length of the interval keeps up with the convergence to $0$ of $f_n$, this is why it converges to $1$. The function $f_n$ converges to $0$ but as $n$ gets larger, the interval you are integrating on compensates.

Comment: @Sorfosh: No, the bound doesn't matter. $\int_a^b f$ is always a short notation for $\int_{\mathbb R}\boldsymbol 1_{(a,b)}f$.

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question. If $|f_n| \leq h$ where $h$ integrable, $f_n \to f$ a.e. ptwise on $[0,\infty)$, and $g(n) \to \infty$, then $$\int_0^{g(n)} f_n = \int 1_{[0,g(n)]} f_n.$$
Then $1_{[0,g(n)]}f_n$ is dominated by $h$ still and $1_{[0,g(n)]} f_n \to f$ on $[0,\infty)$, so:
$$\lim_n \int_0^{g(n)}f_n \to \int_0^\infty f.$$

The intuition is that you'll be eventually integrating over the whole line, so it doesn't matter how you get there.

Comment: "If $|f_n| \leq h$ where $h$ integrable, $f_n \to f$ a.e. ptwise on $[0,\infty)$, and $g(n) \to \infty$, then $$\int_0^{g(n)} f_n = \int 1_{[0,g(n)]} f_n."$$ No, $\int_0^{g(n)} f_n = \int 1_{[0,g(n)]} f_n$ always holds.